# iOS Top Alignment constraint based on screen (superview) height

Tags: ios, storyboard, uikit, xib, nslayoutconstraint

Let's say for example i want my view's top margin be

**30 px for iPhone 6s**

and for the other screen i want to change this constants from 30 to X where X is proportional to total height of screen

i.e.

**36.5 for iPhone X, 
33 for iPhone 6s plus, 
25 for iPhone SE**

And so on .... I know i can take `@IBOutlet` of `NSLayoutConstraint` and change it programmatically but what i want is i want to set it like aspect ratio that we have for height width like subview's heigh width is proportional it's superview it changes with super view's height and width

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The constraint you need here is the superView's centerY set multiplier to 0.5 if you want the top anchor's constant to be 0.25 of screen height from the top , so adjust the multiplier according to this logic which is

> height_of_screen = 2 * centerY

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on just a top constraint like you have. There isn't a way to associate top distance with height from interface builder.

You can add a view above your image that only exists to provide that padding. Your hierarchy will look like this in VFL:

```
"V:|[paddingView][imageView]"
```

Here's an image of the view in place above the image view:

[image: view above image view]

Then you can install a height constraint on that padding view that makes it equal to the containing view.

[image: make heights equal]

Add a multiplier to that constraint that gets you the expected height. If you want it to be 30 on a screen that's 667 points tall, then the multiplier will be something like 0.044978 (30 / 667 = ~0.044978). This height constraint will update depending on the main view height which will provide the desired visual padding.

[image: add multiplier to the constraint]

Comment: Thanks ... Yes i know this padding view solution ... but i was just wondering if same can be achieved without taking extraa views just for padding

Comment: @mihirmehta Agreed, it's not ideal. If I were implementing this, I would most likely just set this constraint in code rather than adding something like this padding view in the xib. Padding views can be confusing when you try to maintain a section far down the road, constraints in code can be commented for clarity.